# parsing JSON request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby, hash

The following `@request = JSON.parse(request.body.read)` is generating:

```
[
  {
    "application_id"=>"216", 
    "description"=>"Please double check date and time", 
    "release_date"=>"2018-12-01", 
    "auth"=>"someBigData"
  }
]
```

However a blank is returned if invoking

```
Rails.logger.info @request['application_id']
```

and

```
if @request['auth'] == 'someBigData'
```

is generating a

> TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer):`  in `app/controllers/base_controller.rb:55:in '[]'

What is wrong syntactically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an array of hashes back, which is why `@request['application_id']` returns a blank for you.

You'll need to do `@request.first['application_id']` or `@request[0]['application_id']` to index into your array.

Answer (score 2):

As it's been already stated, you get this error cause `@request` is an array of hashes rather than a hash itself. To access `"application_id"` key of the first element you can also use `dig` method:

```
@request.dig(0, "application_id")
```

this way there is not going to be an exception in case `@request` is empty.

Comment: While I believe this will not occur in this use-case, the suggestion is pertinent for other instances I can think of.